# Using Python pandas, how do I create a function to calculate the proportion of rows that represent a lower value than the previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

Using Python pandas, how do I create a function to calculate the proportion of rows that represent a lower value than the previous row? 
So in other words, I need a function to iterate through the values under a particular series column of a Pandas Data Frame and only count those values where the next row's value (under say column called 'Mileage') is less than the current row's value. Like say you have this: 
Mileage:
row 1: 30
row 2: 20
row 3: 40
row 4: 50
row 5: 60
row 6: 55
row 7: 75

If the counter is working correctly, it would spot that row 2's value of 20 is less than row 1's value of 30 and so it would add +1 to counter (count that one).
In the example above, another row that it should count is row 6: 55 which is < than its previous row 5: 60 and so count that one.
And so the final count would be: 2.
And then I can divide that final count by total row count to get a proportion.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `series.shift` function:

```
proportion = len(df[df['Mileage'] < df['Mileage'].shift(1)])/len(df)
print(proportion)
```

output:

```
0.2857142857142857
```

the part of the code:

```
df[df['Mileage'] < df['Mileage'].shift(1)]
```

Uses masking to only select rows that meet that condition (in this case 2), and so we take the `len` of that divided by the total `len` of the df and get the proportion.
`.shift(1)` allows you to access the next rows value so you can compare to the current row in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas function [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'mileage': [30,20,40,50,60,55,75] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
smaller_rows = (df.mileage < df.mileage.shift()).sum()
print(smaller_rows)
out[]: 2
```

How does it work? Shift(), as the name says shifts the values of the mileage column by 1 row further (default 1, any amount can be specified via the key `periods`). Then both DataFrames are compared to each other which creates an array of booleans. Applying `sum()` will count the number of True's.

To get the proportion, you want to divide `smaller_rows` by the total amount of rows, like this:

```
proportion = smaller_rows/len(df)
```

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you!!